# KinematicBody2D not moving in Godot

Tags: godot

I wrote some code for basic movement of a square character and it doesn’t seem to work, there were no errors and I did the indentation of the if statements correct it think, here’s the code:

```
Extends KinematicBody2D
var movespeed = 500
    
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.
func _physics_process(delta):
    var motion = Vector2()
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("up"):
        motion.y -= 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("down"):
            motion.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        motion.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        motion.x -= 1
    
    motion = motion.normalized()
    motion = move_and_slide(motion * movespeed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Your indentation for the third if statement is wrong, it should be left one tab.

Secondly, if you add a `ui_` to the front of `"up"`, `"down"`, etc. it should work assuming you haven't changed the settings as suggested by [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15447865/stephen-dunn). These are mapped to the arrow keys by default.

Having created a blank project, the following code works in place of your existing statements:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
    motion.y -= 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    motion.y += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    motion.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    motion.x -= 1
```

Lastly, the `Extends` at the beginning is definitely wrong and will throw an error, it should be `extends`.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You code works, but you need to make sure that "up" "down" "left" "right" is present in your inputmap, without that, the code will run, but the character won't move.

Todo this, menu top left press "Project" then "Project Settings", then select Input Map tab.

You need add actions, so up, down, left right, and then once you add them, find them at the bottom of that list, and assign the key on your keyboard you wish to control the character. This is what I had to do with your code to get it working.

Comment: Thanks but it still didnt work and its not moving